# React-Native wrapper class for iOS & android libraries

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I am learning RN, and would like to create a consistent interface (a wrapper) for two libraries doing the same thing on different platforms, for example, DatePickerIOS & react-native-wheel-picker-android.

I tried `Platform.OS === 'android'`, etc, or `Platform.select`, but not sure if they work on importing libraries as `import {DatePickerIOS} from 'react-native'`

Do I have to import both libraries in my wrapper?  Can I import only the library for the target platform at build time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better you can create a 2 separate files and react native will know which one to use based on the platform it is running on and the file name.

*.android.js will be loaded into the bundle on android
*.ios.js will be loaded into the bundle on ios

create datepicker.android.js and import react-native-wheel-picker-android
write your logic for the android picker in that file.

create datepicker.ios.js and import DatePickerIOS ...